# HTML formatted email using bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, mailx

This is my below script which is working fine as it send only plain text email.

So My question is- How can I modify my below script to send this as an HTML formatted email? I want to show the text color of this expression `(echo "100*$TEST2/$TEST1" | bc -l)` as `RED` in an email and that can be done only in HTML formatted emails. So that is the reason I was thinking to send an email in HTML formatted way. Any suggestions will be of great help.

```
#!/bin/bash

TEN_DAYS="3793274 230667"

TEST1=`echo $TEN_DAYS | awk '{print $1}'`
echo $TEST1

TEST2=`echo $TEN_DAYS | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $TEST2

mailx -s "Report" -r uname@host.com uname@host.com <<EOF

Error  Percentage: `(echo "100*$TEST2/$TEST1" | bc -l)`

EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ways of sending html type emails with mailx

http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/37480-display-html-text-body-using-unix-mailx.html